# Just installed ubuntu 11.10. Looking for a nice, easy to install theme

Tags: themes

I don't like the current theme, or this dock on the left side.

I'm looking for a nice glassy or chrome theme, that is not a port of osx or windows.  I guess if I get instructions for how to install one, from there I'd be able to find others.

So if anyone can walk me through installing a relatively simple theme, maybe with a nice dock, I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the position of the dock but for themes there are some in official repositories.

[Gnome-Look](http://gnome-look.org) is the place for all your themes need.

There are some ppa's to install some famous themes and icon-set:

[Equinox-Theme and Faenza-ICons](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=121881)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-equinox equinox-theme faenza-icon-theme
```

[Elementary theme/Icon](http://danrabbit.deviantart.com/art/elementary-gtk-theme-83104033)
I think you get it from official repository.

[Orta theme](http://skiesofazel.deviantart.com/art/Orta-184118297) which also recommend Faenza Icons

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nikount/orta-desktop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install orta-theme
```

I myself use [Zukitwo](http://lassekongo83.deviantart.com/art/Zukitwo-203936861) with [Faenza-Cupertino](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Faenza-Cupertino?content=129008) from [webupd8-themes-ppa](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/announcing-webupd8-themes-ppa.html)

For dock: There are also various choices in the official repositories like `avant-window-navigator` or `docky` or `cairo-docks` Or a [new and a simple dock `plank`](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/two-neat-themes-for-plank/) which can be installed from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/docky)

Comment: [code]$ sudo apt-get install orta-theme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package orta-theme[/code]

Comment: Seems like orta has not been ported to `oneiric` what you can do is install `webupd8-themes` ppa which includes a mintified orta theme i.e. default theme of Linux Mint.

Comment: Thanks.  So what commmand could I use to get orta through webupd8?

Comment: Well its not `orta` but from the same author for Linux Mint so its greenish `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/themes &&
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mint-x-theme mint-z-theme` There are other themes on this repository as well you may try others as well

Comment: Thanks for this, especially the **webupd8-themes-ppa** pointer. You might want to note that the Equinox theme won't really work under 11.10, since it hasn't been ported to GTK3.

Comment: Wait, my mistake — the window decorations still work it seems.